# I have received this error in C++ but cannot figure out why, (I am a first year college student)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

So, I have recently started learning C++ (I am in first year college). I have been stuck with this error for a while now and none of my peers have been able to assist me in fixing this issue.
The error I am receiving is error: expected '{' before else
Here is the code:

```
switch (selectOption)
    {

    case 1:
        cout << "Enter amount of people" << endl;
        cin >> amountPpl;

        //validating that there is more than 0 people
        if (amountPpl > 0)
         {
           total = amountPpl * 30;
            cout << "Your total for " << amountPpl << " is R" << total << endl;
         }
        else
          {
            cout << "You can't enter 0 people" << endl;
          }
    break ;

    case 2:
        cout << "Enter amount of Students" << endl;
        cin >> amountPpl;

        //validating input
        if (amountPpl > 0)
        {
          total = amountPpl * 25;
          cout << "The amount for " << amountPpl << "students is R" << total << endl;
          }
        else
        {
          cout << "You can't enter 0 people" << endl;
        }
    break;

    case 3:
        cout << "Are There any additional children? Answer with y/n" << endl;
        cin >> decision;

        //validating input
        if (decision == 'y')
        {
         cout << "Please enter amount of additional children" << endl;
         cin >> extraKids;

            if (extraKids > 0)
            {
                total = 75 + (extraKids * 15 );
                cout << "Your total is R" << total << "For the family package" << endl;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "You cant enter 0 kids" << endl;
            }


            else // ***ERROR*** is here 
            {
              cout << "Your total is R75";
            }
        }
    break;

    default:
        cout << "invalid input, you can only select a number from 1-3 ";
    }
```

[link to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Kt3.png)

Comment: You cannot use `else` without corresponding `if`. What do you want to do?

Comment: No images of errors please. Post them as text formatted in a code block like you did with your code

Comment: The "error is here" branch should belong to the `if (decision == 'y')` condition, but you happened to write it before the closing `}` of that branch instead of after it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this section:

```
if (extraKids > 0)
{
    total = 75 + (extraKids * 15 );
    cout << "Your total is R" << total << "For the family package" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "You cant enter 0 kids" << endl;
}
else // ***ERROR*** is here 
{
    cout << "Your total is R75";
}
```

@MikeCAT is correct. You cannot have two `else` sections. The first `else` should become an `else if`. The condition is obvious from the output string.